# Stuck on Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, thm. 14.2

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Theorem 14.2.**
>   Let $f$ map a region $\Omega$ into the plane. If $f'(z_0)$ exists at some $z_0\in\Omega$ and $f'(z_0)\neq 0$, then $f$ preserves angles at $z_0$. Conversely, if the differential of $f$ exists and is different from $0$ at $z_0$, and if $f$ preserves angles at $z_0$, then $f'(z_0)$ exists and is different from $0$.
>
> The differential of $f$ at $z_0$ is a linear transformation $L$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that, writing $z_0 = (x_0, y_0),$
>   \begin{align}\tag{1}f(x_0 + x, y_0 + y) = f(x_0, y_0) + L(x,y) + ||(x,y)||_2\eta (x,y),\end{align}
>   where $\eta(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.
>
> **Proof:** 
>   Take $z_0=f(z_0)=0$, for simplicity. If $f'(0)=a\neq 0$, then it is immediate that
>   \begin{align}
> e^{i\theta} A[f(re^{i\theta})]=\frac{e^{-i\theta}f(re^{i\theta})}{|f(re^{i\theta})|}\rightarrow \frac{a}{|a|} && (r\rightarrow 0)\tag{2}
> \end{align}
>   so f preserves angles at 0. Conversely, if the differential of $f$ exists at $0$ and is different from $0$, then $(1)$ can be rewritten in the form
>   \begin{align}\tag{3}
> f(z) = \alpha z + \beta \bar{z} + |z|\eta(z)
> \end{align}
>   where $\eta(z)\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow 0$, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex number, not both $0$. If $f$ also preserves angles at $0$, then
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{r\rightarrow 0} e^{-i\theta}A[f(re^{i\theta})]=\frac{\alpha+\beta e^{-2i\theta}}{|\alpha + \beta e^{-2i\theta}|}\tag{4}
> \end{align}
>   exists and is independent of $\theta$. We may exclude those $\theta$ for which the denominator in $(4)$ is $0$; there are at most two such $\theta$ in $[0, 2\pi)$. For all other $\theta$, we conclude that $\alpha + \beta e^{-2i\theta}$ lies on a fixed ray through $0$, and this is possible when $\beta = 0$. Hence $\alpha \neq 0$, and $(3)$ implies that $f'(0)=\alpha$.

I can't figure out how to conclude $(3)$ from $(1)$. If $z_0=(0,0)$, then LHS of $(1)$ is $f(z)$ and $||(x, y)||_2$ is $|z|$. Why $f(x_0, y_0) + L(x, y)$ can be rewritten as $\alpha z + \beta \bar{z}$?

Comment: I don't believe it actually says "(...)" at the start of the proof - I suspect the answer to your question is there in the part you omitted.

Comment: Theorem 14.2 has two parts. First, the ommited one, refers to converse of theorem that I asked. It states that if $f'(z_0)$ exist at some $z_0\in\Omega$ and $f'(z_0)\neq 0$, then $f$ preserves angles at $z_0$. I also ommited one-line proof of this fact.

Comment: [Sigh] You asked why (3) follows from (1). It's clear that (3) simply does not follow from (1), literally speaking. Somewhere in the part you omitted, possibly in the proof of the first part, there are a few words like "assume that..." or "without loss of generality..." or something. My copy of the book is missing, but I know that Rudin is not saying that (3) actually follows from (1).

Comment: And sure enough, the answer to your question is right there at the start of what you omitted. "Take $z_0=f(z_0)=0$". Did you notice the $f(z_0)=0$ part? _Given_ that, (1) is just $f(x,y)=L(x,y)+\dots$.

Comment: Now I got it, thanks.

Comment: Not sure why Rudin doesn't just go the CR eons in proving angle preserving implies f'(z_0) exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof in the book starts off with the (without loss of generality) assumption(s) that  $z_0= x_0+iy_0= 0$, and that $f(z_0)=f(x_0,y_0) =0$. For the other point: $L$ is a real-linear map from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$: $$L \in E \ \overset{\rm def}{=}\  {\rm hom}_{\mathbb R}( {\mathbb C}, {\mathbb C} ) \simeq {\rm hom}_{\mathbb R}( {\mathbb C}, {\mathbb R} )\otimes {\mathbb C}.$$
From the second expression, the space of such $L$ is $2$ dimensional over $\mathbb C$. The maps 
$$ x+iy\mapsto x \text{ and } x+iy\mapsto y $$
form a basis (over the complexes) for $E$, but so do

$$ x+iy \mapsto x+iy \text{ and }x+iy \mapsto x-iy.$$

Of course, really, all we are saying is that $x =( z +\bar z )/2$ and $y = (z-\bar z)/2i$.

Comment: Without using tensor product, is it possible to rewrite $L(x,y)$ as $\alpha z+ \beta \bar z$?

Comment: @Error404: Sure.  $L (x,y) = xa+ yb$, with $a$ and $b$ complex, because $L$ is $\mathbb R$-linear - we are identifying  $\mathbb C$ and 
 $\mathbb R^2$, by using $1$ and $i$ as real basis. So, on substituting in the expressions (see "all we are saying..." above) for $x$ and $y$, and re-arranging, one has  $$\matrix{L(x,y) & = a ( z + \overline z)/2 + b ( z-\overline z) /2i \\ & = {(a/2+ b/2i)} z + {(a/2-b/2i) }  \overline z.}$$  OK?

Comment: Okay. But why does $L$ being $\Bbb R$-linear and identifying $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$ imply $L(x,y)=xa+yb$ for some complex numbers $a,b$?

Comment: If $L(1,0) = a$, and $L(0,1) = b$, then by real linearity, $L(x,y) = xa + yb$.

Comment: hats off to you. I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks a lot for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: It's good of you to be conscientious, and to clear to up doubts... Have fun with the book (and the course?)  - I remember liking it ( both ?) very much.

Comment: Indeed!! I like this book too along with the course. :)